# Angular js filter drop down options based on some constant value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I list drop-down options from below Json object where `IsDeleted == 0`

```
"currencies":[{
    "CurrencyID":"1",
    "CurrencyCode":"AED",
    "CurrencyName":"United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "IsDeleted":"1"
},{
    "CurrencyID":"2",
    "CurrencyCode":"AFN",
    "CurrencyName":"Afghan Afghani",
    "IsDeleted":"1"
},{
    "CurrencyID":"3",
    "CurrencyCode":"ALL",
    "CurrencyName":"Albanian Lek",
    "IsDeleted":"1"
}];


<select ng-model="data.CurrencyID" ng-options="cu.CurrencyID as cu.CurrencyName for cu in currencies | filter : IsDeleted :'0'"></select>
```

Comment: Actually problem is with default value assigned to currencies as $scope.currencies = {}; which throws error and filter stops working.. Whenever filter is used on json array the default value should not be $scope.currencies = {};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="data.CurrencyID" ng-options="cu.CurrencyID as cu.CurrencyName for cu in currencies |filter : {IsDeleted :'0'}"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the IsDeleted : '0' just replace " : " by " = " operator after isDeleted

```html
<select ng-model="data.CurrencyID" ng-options="cu.CurrencyID as cu.CurrencyName for cu in currencies | filter : IsDeleted = '0'"></select>
```